# Luxand API in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing, emgucv

How can I use Luxand API to get to work in visual studio 2010? I need to detect points of chin in a given face, can I do it with any other API?

I have tried this sample code:

```
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                FSDK.CImage image = new FSDK.CImage(openFileDialog1.FileName);

                // resize image to fit the window width
                double ratio = System.Math.Min((pictureBox1.Width + 0.4) / image.Width,
                    (pictureBox1.Height + 0.4) / image.Height);
                image = image.Resize(ratio);

                Image frameImage = image.ToCLRImage();
                Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(frameImage);

                FSDK.TFacePosition facePosition = image.DetectFace();
                if (0 == facePosition.w)
                    MessageBox.Show("No faces detected", "Face Detection");
                else
                {
                    int left = facePosition.xc - facePosition.w / 2;
                    int top = facePosition.yc - facePosition.w / 2;
                    gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightGreen, left, top, facePosition.w, facePosition.w);

                    FSDK.TPoint[] facialFeatures = image.DetectFacialFeaturesInRegion(ref facePosition);
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (FSDK.TPoint point in facialFeatures)
                        gr.DrawEllipse((++i > 2) ? Pens.LightGreen : Pens.Blue, point.x, point.y, 3, 3);

                    gr.Flush();
                }

                // display image
                pictureBox1.Image = frameImage;
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception");
            }
        }
```

I get this error:
Could not load file or assembly 'xquisite.application.exe' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: Did you try anything? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I tried writing a program using it in VS 2010 but it does not work.

Comment: I get this error: Could not load file or assembly 'xQuisite Application.exe' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is your settings for your target? Any CPU ? Try `x86` for Runtime ! 
have you add to your app.config `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"/>`
 ? 
These two thinks i forgot, were the reason of my errors which was the same as yours.

here is a piece of my code:

```
        private void DetectFace()
    {
        var failerCounter = 0;
        var cameraHandler = 0;
        try
        {
            const int failerLimit = 2;
            int failerLimitFaceDetection = Properties.Settings.Default.NotDetectedLimit;
            float similarityMinimum = Properties.Settings.Default.SimilarityLimit;

            var r = FSDKCam.OpenVideoCamera(ref CameraName, ref cameraHandler);
            if (r != FSDK.FSDKE_OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(StringHelper.ErrorCamera);
            }
            FSDK.SetFaceDetectionParameters(
                Properties.Settings.Default.DetectionHandleArbitaryRotations,
                Properties.Settings.Default.DetectionDetermineFaceRotationAngle,
                Properties.Settings.Default.DetectionInternalResizeWidth);
            FSDK.SetFaceDetectionThreshold(Properties.Settings.Default.DetectionFaceDetectionThreshold);

            while (IsFaceDetectionActive)
            {
                var imageHandle = 0;
                if (FSDK.FSDKE_OK != FSDKCam.GrabFrame(cameraHandler, ref imageHandle))
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate { }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
                    continue;
                }
                var image = new FSDK.CImage(imageHandle);
                var frameImage = image.ToCLRImage();
                FaceContent = frameImage;
                var gr = Graphics.FromImage(frameImage);
                var facePosition = image.DetectFace();

                IsFaceDetected = facePosition.w != 0;
                if (!IsFaceDetected)
                {
                    if (failerCounter++ > failerLimitFaceDetection)
                    {
                        failerCounter = 0;
                        OnFaceNotDetected();
                    }
                }
                // if a face is detected, we detect facial features
                if (IsFaceDetected)
                {
                    var facialFeatures = image.DetectFacialFeaturesInRegion(ref facePosition);
                    SmoothFacialFeatures(ref facialFeatures);
                    FaceTemplate = image.GetFaceTemplate();
                    // Similarity = 0.5f -> fin the right value ....
                    IsFaceRecognized = FaceMetricHandler.LooksLike(FaceTemplate, similarityMinimum).Any();

                    if (IsFaceRecognized)
                    {
                        foreach (var match in FaceMetricHandler.LooksLike(FaceTemplate, similarityMinimum))
                        {
                            failerCounter = 0;
                            GreetingMessage = match.Name;
                            IsFaceDetectionActive = false;
                            OnFaceRecognized();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (failerCounter++ > failerLimit)
                        {
                            failerCounter = 0;
                            IsFaceDetectionActive = false;
                            OnFaceNotRecognized();
                        }
                    }


                    if (IsFaceFrameActive)
                    {
                        gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, facePosition.xc - 2*facePosition.w/3,
                                         facePosition.yc - facePosition.w/2,
                                         4*facePosition.w/3, 4*facePosition.w/3);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ResetSmoothing();
                }
                FaceContent = frameImage;
                GC.Collect();
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate { }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.Fatal(e.Message);
            InitializeCamera();
        }
        finally
        {
            FSDKCam.CloseVideoCamera(cameraHandler);
            FSDKCam.FinalizeCapturing();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Its been quite a while since I needed this, but it works perfect!! Thankyou so much :)

Comment: :) great than happy coding :) If you want, i have a beautiful MVVC App which recognize when somebody comes to the camera and you can safe your facemetric with your name and when you goe away and came back it recognized it again and say hello 'username' and you have a survey : like facescann or dislike ;)

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you can use x64 with win64\FaceSDK.NET.dll